# CodeIgniter - Unable to Locate Class

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am new to codeIgniter and facing issue while extending a controller. I do know there is answer on stackoverflow but it is relevant to extending a core class and does not provide me solution. As given below, I want to extend 'Auth_controller' but doing so gives me class not found error

MY Auth_controller

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');



abstract class  Auth_Controller extends CI_Controller {


public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();

    $this->load->library('session');
    $this->load->model('login_model');

    if(!$this->session->userdata('u_id')){
        return redirect(base_url('admin/login'));
    }
    else
    {
        if(!$this->login_model->do_check_login($this->session->u_id,$this->session->email,$this->session->session_id,$this->session->role_id))
        {
            return redirect(base_url('admin/login'));

        }
        echo "login successful";

    }



}

public abstract function index();
```

}

My Dashboar_controller

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');


class Dashboard_controller extends Auth_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library('email');
        $this->load->library('calendar');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        //my code here
    }
}


error
```

> Fatal error: Class 'Auth_Controller' not found in C:\xampp1\htdocs\Admin\application\controllers\admin\Dashboard_controller.php on line 4

[image: Error Image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/21351808/594235

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27910751/594235

Comment: Maybe look at the docs too.  https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html#organizing-your-controllers-into-sub-directories

Comment: is `Auth_Controller` in `application/core`? in such a case you should either call it `MY_Controller` or require it in a file that is always loaded, like the config.php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to add `require_once('Auth_controller.php')` at the top of Dashboard_controller.php; otherwise the Dashboard file will not know about the Auth class. (See [require_once](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php) in the php docs).

https://stackoverflow.com/a/27910751/594235